# Google Maps Api v3 - wrong location on map plot load

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I need help for my google map api in my website. I included the map in my website and then automatically plots my location or locate me, but the problem is it gives me wrong location but some location are correct.

This is my website : `http://webserver.site88.net/beta-test`

**Here is mycode:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function writeAddressName(latLng) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
      "location": latLng
    },
    function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
        document.getElementById("address").value = results[0].formatted_address;
      else
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += "Unable to retrieve your address" + "<br />";
    });
  }

  function geolocationSuccess(position) {
    var userLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    document.getElementById("inLat").value = position.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById("inLong").value = position.coords.longitude;

    // Write the formatted address
    writeAddressName(userLatLng);

    var myOptions = {
      zoom : 16,
      center : userLatLng,
      mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      location_type: google.maps.GeocoderLocationType.ROOFTOP
    };
    // Draw the map
    var mapObject = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
    // Place the marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: mapObject,
      position: userLatLng
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<div>'+'<b>'+'You are here '+'</b>'+'</div>'
    });


    infowindow.open(mapObject,marker);

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', geolocateUser);
  }

  function geolocationError(positionError) {
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += "Error: " + positionError.message + "<br />";
  }

  function geolocateUser() {
    // If the browser supports the Geolocation API
    if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
      var positionOptions = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 10 * 1000 // 10 seconds
      };
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess, geolocationError, positionOptions);
    }
    else
      document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += "Your browser doesn't support the Geolocation API";


}
</script>
```

Comment: What are the locations that are wrong? Which are correct?

Comment: we ask some people to try our website, they came from different places most of them is like 16 hours drive, and the maps gives wrong location.

current location of all the users are here in the Philippines

Comment: when the browser returns a wrong location he is not able to locate the user more correctly(usually a correct location will be returned only when a GPS-device or WI-FI is available, otherwise the process will be IP-based, what may not result in a  exact location)

Comment: Thank you very much Dr. Molle! I thought there is something wrong in my codes.